# What is the term for an undirected graph that's not a tree?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

What is the term for an undirected graph in which a path can start from node $A$ and return to $A$ without traversing any edge twice?  My first guess would be to call it a "cyclic" graph, but that can't be right, since many directed *acyclic* graphs have the property I have in mind.  Of course such DAGs are acyclic in a different sense that reflects their directedness.  I'd like a term that applies whether the graph is directed or not.

EDIT: The original question above was ambiguous.  There are two concepts that I could have been asking about, depending on whether "some" or "every" is used in the following:
What is the term for an undirected graph in which, for {*every, some*} node $A$, there is a path that starts at $A$ and returns to $A$ without traversing any edge twice.

arbolverde provided a good answer for the "every" question.  I am also interested in the answer for the "some" question, which is what's implied by the title of the question.

Comment: I call it cyclic, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the graph is undirected, I think the term you are looking for
is 2-connected. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BiconnectedGraph.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @crash It looks to me that the essential part of the answer is right here: "the term is 2-connected", and the link is merely a reference for more.

Comment: Thanks arbolverde.  "2-connected" and "biconnected" mean the same thing?  @crash, I think Famous Blue Raincoat is right that what alboverde has given is a full answer, even if it would be even more helpful if the answer connected my specification to the definition given in the link.  I see the equivalence of the definition to what I specified, however.  (However, I also realized that what I actually had in mind was something slightly different.  But I should ask a new question about that other concept.)

Comment: On second thought, after reflecting on your answer, arbolverde, I think that my question was ambiguous, so that I was really asking two questions; you answered one of them.  I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: @Mars For the "some" part of your new question (and only talking in undirected graphs). If I understood it well, you are looking for the name of a graph that has at least one cycle, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's right, arbolverde.  (There are things that one can do with a tree that can't be done as soon as there are cycles, or can't be done easily: You can remove a subtree from a tree by cutting the edge to the "top" node of the subtree, without having to worry about whether other nodes in the subtree connect to nodes outside the subtree.  That may not be true if there are cycles.  I'm trying to figure out how to refer to the things that aren't trees throughout, in order to make it easier to talk about this kind of difference.)

Comment: I may be wrong, but I suspect that there is not a name for what you are looking for. Maybe you should refer them as non-trees or put a new fancy name to them. Can I know what do you need that name for? Maybe it is not very necessary to name that class of graphs everytime.

Comment: Thinking a litle more, I think that the class of graphs you are looking for is exactly the connected graphs with more than n-1 edges, where n is the number of vertices of the graph. It is the more close to a name that I can think about.

Comment: Thanks, arbolverde for being so helpful. Doesn't roll of the tongue, but I guess I can't do better. The immediate need was to talk about programming a network diagram. The D3.js library makes it relatively easy to create a [network diagram in which clicking on a node](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288) "collapses" edges and nodes farther out. Lacking terminology hinders discussion of providing similar functions for a ... non-tree, e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161702/d3-collapsible-graph?noredirect=1#comment45294609_17161702). Working on the code. Will think about a name.